# Export Orders from Magento 2 database to another Magento 2 database

Tags: magento2, database, orders

Is it possible to move orders from one Magento 2 database to another? Or can I manually add the information in the database table (if so what is the table(s) called?

I only have 10 orders to move across but would like them to show identical information (i.e. including the payment gateway transaction details).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dump for these tables for all orders records:

```
`gift_message`

`quote`

`quote_address`

`quote_address_item`

`quote_id_mask`

`quote_item`

`quote_item_option`

`quote_payment`

`quote_shipping_rate`

`reporting_orders`

`sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`

`sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`

`sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`

`sales_creditmemo`

`sales_creditmemo_comment`

`sales_creditmemo_grid`

`sales_creditmemo_item`

`sales_invoice`

`sales_invoiced_aggregated`

`sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`

`sales_invoice_comment`

`sales_invoice_grid`

`sales_invoice_item`

`sales_order`

`sales_order_address`

`sales_order_aggregated_created`

`sales_order_aggregated_updated`

`sales_order_grid`

`sales_order_item`

`sales_order_payment`

`sales_order_status_history`

`sales_order_tax`

`sales_order_tax_item`

`sales_payment_transaction`

`sales_refunded_aggregated`

`sales_refunded_aggregated_order`

`sales_shipment`

`sales_shipment_comment`

`sales_shipment_grid`

`sales_shipment_item`

`sales_shipment_track`

`sales_shipping_aggregated`

`sales_shipping_aggregated_order`

`tax_order_aggregated_created`

`tax_order_aggregated_updated`
```